# Ho to use ftp_put for file upload in PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

I try to upload a file using `ftp_put` after submitting a form. However my code does not work as expected:

```php
$ftpHost   = '192.168.180.36';
$ftpUsername = 'userdownload';
$ftpPassword = 'Toms!';
$filepath = "C://xampp/htdocs/Helpdesk/fmt/download";
$connId = ftp_connect($ftpHost,21) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftpHost");
$ftpLogin = ftp_login($connId, $ftpUsername, $ftpPassword);

$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
// try to upload file
if(ftp_put($connId, $file_name, $filepath.'/'.$file_name, FTP_BINARY)){
    echo "File transfer successful - $file_name";
}else{
    echo "There was an error while uploading $file_name";
}
```

And I get this error message:

> There was an error while uploading $file_name

Comment: Look at the parameters to `ftp_put`. The third parameter in your code should probably be `$tmp_name`

Comment: @ReddHerring, are you sure $tmp_name ? how about $filepath ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing i noticed in your code. the first one is the mode of transfer depends upon your file type.Files that are in the ascii/text file extension list are transferred as ascii, all other files are transferred as binary.The second one is may be there is a problem in your file which you received may be it is black first check that. You can try this code it is working for me.

```
  <?php
    // connect and login to FTP server
    $ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

    $file = "localfile.txt";

    // upload file
    if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "serverfile.txt", $file, FTP_ASCII))
      {
      echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Error uploading $file.";
      }
    // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I choose ftp_binary because upload file like pdf format.can you share me link of `serverfile.txt`?

Comment: Ok. serverfile.txt is a file name where you can upload your file.like i have https://www.xaml.com/admin/img/serverfile.txt

Comment: page not found btw.

Comment: That was an example of same link.Sorry i can't provide you the real link because of security purpose.it is in production